# I have a list of file names and I need to be able to count how many of the same file gets repeated for each file name

Tags: python, arrays, list, count

Here is part of my list:

```
  mi_navif.c,   mi_navif.c

  svd_state_check_sqif.c

  acq_statistics.c

  mei_hostHandler.c, mei_tbus.c

  gr_coloc.c, gr_nav.c

  atxcm_meas.c

  svd_bds.c, svd_state_check_sqif.c

  tc_control.c
```

So how do I write a command to view each kind of word and how many times it appears? I'm new to this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this list in a file? do you already have a python list?

Comment: Well I have a list in a word document that I want to find the number of instances using python. But to do that, the words have to have quotation marks and commas. Is there an easy way to add these for separate words? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a list of filenames use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
files = ["foo.txt","foo.txt","foobar.c"]

c = Counter(files)
print (c)
Counter({'foo.txt': 2, 'foobar.c': 1})
```

The `keys` will be your files and the `values` will be how many times the file appears in your list: